# Make [tmpfile] a synonym for [temporary-files]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Please make [tmpfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tmpfile) a synonym for [temporary-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/temporary-files)

[tmpfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tmpfile): •Tag wiki ✗   •Questions tagged: 33
[temporary-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/temporary-files): •Tag wiki ✔ •Questions tagged: 293

The [tag info for temporary-files](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/temporary-files/info) says:

> A (often short lived) file, automatically created for reasons like storing data that no longer fit into memory, for inter-process communication or to save state for possible crash recovery. Many programming platforms provide means functions to work with such files easier.

This description is applicable for [tmpfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tmpfile) too. They are synonymous.

Comment: There is also [tag:tempfile]. This one should also be made a synonym of [tag:temporary-files].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done and Done - both [tmpfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tmpfile) and [tempfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tempfile) are now synonyms of [temporary-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/temporary-files).