# How do you actually get a synonym approved?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonym-process

So,
I proposed two synonyms about a year ago that I believe are extremely obvious, and they didn't get even a single vote:

- [sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sync) for [synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronization): [Synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synchronization/synonyms).
- [asynchronous-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asynchronous-processing) for [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asynchronous): [Synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asynchronous/synonyms).

Am I doing it right? Was I supposed to post an announcement on meta?

If not, then I think the process doesn't work. Wouldn't a synonym review queue with all the associated badges work better?

Comment: You better make a meta post... oh, you just did....

Comment: A couple years ago I posted a meta question asking why a moderator didn't handle a synonym request (and instead just posted a comment about another (wrong if that matters) synonym request for the same tag) and it was closed as a duplicate of the original request (even though the two questions were different as one asked for the actual synonymification and the other just asked "why didn't the mod do anything?").

Comment: IMHO it is impossible. I did some hard work to get enough reputation on a tag to propose a synonym and it was never accepted. Instead some moderator got month later the same idea with a little other naming and merged all tags almost the same like I tried it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can post a [synonym-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synonym-request) here on MSO [like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275670/make-tmpfile-a-synonym-for-temporary-files)

Comment: Wouldn't it be more wise if we just retag this post?

Comment: @rene I think Infinite Recursion's answer was more meant as a general answer, not only for this specific tag. The question also asks about getting tag synonyms approved in general.

Comment: @rene: this post is a feature request for a new queue for synonyms. OP used the synonyms only to exemplify the current situation. This post is NOT a synonym-request. Retagging will be invalid and conflict with the author's intent.

Comment: Sure, but if I remove the last sentence my point becomes valid. This OP's initial (and I assume, I know that is tricky) and only intent is to get those synonyms approved, not get involved in some meta discussion if this post is a correct way to do that....

Comment: @rene Considering it's tagged [tag:discussion] and [tag:feature-request], I think we're better off treating it in that light and possibly making this a canonical Q&A for synonyms.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I already accepted defeat... by a Duck :(

Comment: [Make sync a synonym of synchronization](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278225/885318).

Answer (score 7):

There is kind of a queue for synonym suggestions.  However, I don't think many people look at it:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest

<s>It also seems that it only shows a small fraction of the actual suggestions. I wonder why that is.</s>

That view will show you all suggested synonyms that you are allowed to vote on (having enough rep in the associated master tag).

The "all" tab will show all suggestions, but you can't filter or sort them out from all the existing synonyms.

Comment: If it's undocumented (like the timeline view), it's likely unsupported. Is it documented?

Comment: It is linked to by every synonym page (that is how I found it).  You can get to it with 3 clicks from the front page (Click on tag -> Synonyms -> See all tag Synonyms).  I guess that counts as documented?

Comment: I'd just never seen it, but thanks for directing me to it. That's why I thought it was undocumented.

Comment: Yea, it isn't something you would see unless you went digging for it.

Comment: I *think* it only shows the suggestions that you can vote on. (Though I think the rules that decide what synonyms you can vote on is part of the reason why suggested tag synonyms pretty much don't work.)

Comment: @svick ah ha, that makes sense.  Thanks for pointing that out.