# Make [sync] a synonym of [synchronization]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Please make [sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sync) a synonym of [synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronization).

[synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronization) - 4,977 questions. Tag Info:

> Synchronization refers to using controls to maintain a coherent representation, either a group of processes running the same program (process synchronization), or representations of data (data synchronization)..

[sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sync) - 1,823 questions. Tag Info:

> Sync is a synonym for Synchronization, which refers to using controls to maintain a coherent representation, either a group of processes running the same program (process synchronization), or representations of data (data synchronization).

I've already suggested it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synchronization/synonyms)

Comment: what about synchronous vs. asynchronous?

Comment: @DanielA.White What about it?

Comment: could this add any confusion?

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't really get where you're going with this. synchronization could be either synchronous or asynchronous. It's not a synonym...

Comment: i mean that async is short for asynchronous - some may see sync as short for synchronous.

Comment: @DanielA.White oh, got it. So what do you suggest? since sync is already out there and it means synchronization?

Answer (score 9):

**Yes**, the way the current tag info and especially excerpt for [sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sync) are written ("is a synonym for Synchronization") it should be easy to merge it with [synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronization) (and while at it, also with [synchronisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronisation) and [synchronize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronize)).

**However**, the term *sync* does also abbreviate [synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synchronous), which means something entirely different. Similarly, [async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async) is already a synonym for [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asynchronous).

Before merging them, it should be evaluated how many of them were tagged with the second meaning in mind (contrary to the excerpt). An example would be the question [Make 1 method async as well as sync in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056798/make-1-method-async-as-well-as-sync-in-c-sharp). From my first look they seem to be rare, but they would need to be retagged.